# make a django run or redirect to login page instead of leading me to "index of"

Tags: django, apache

Am currently working on a site set by another developer..I want the site to redirect me to say login page but it leads me to "index of" page where it just shows the scripts in my folder.
The developer has mod_wsgi already installed..
perhaps if you guide me on how to write a .htaccess or wsgi script to have this site run i will be much grateful.
The site is in `/home/asdcopjg/afteryes/floralfox` if that file structure will help you help me
If there is anything that you will want me to provide so that you can assist please let me know or add comment.
Regards,
Joshua

Comment: you can't change the view function ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add @login_required decorator in the index view, if you do that by mod_rewrite nobody will be able to access index even they successfully log in.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator